# Loading JavaScript when div has loaded?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a script that will reload the page (content) to a random DIV
How do I implement this so that the script loads after the div is loaded?

I have the following code ready:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#getAssignment").click(function() {
      var $divs = $(".assignment");
      if ($divs.length > 0) {
         window.location.hash = "#" + $divs[ Math.floor(Math.random() * 
         $divs.length) ].id;
      }
  });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: You can try onload function for that

Comment: onLoad event in div should do it

Comment: This question is not very clear.  Do you have code that is dynamically loading content into a div?  If so, please show that code.

Comment: div's don't load.  div's are just part of the larger page.  If you're changing what's inside a div, then whatever code is doing that can trigger whatever you want to happen afterward...

Comment: sorry, this script is usually done when the user click on a button and the script will then select a random div from a list of them (they are classes as "assignment") I want to do the same thing, but instead when this particular page(which is a DIV) is loaded

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").load(function(){
    blah();
});
```

This will do what you wanted, but it does not make sense though, since `div` is not like an image or `<script>` or a page. (You can't really "load" a `<div>` anyway.)

Comment: sorry guys, I'm really stupid when it comes to code...how do I make the onload function work with what I have?

Comment: sorry, this script is usually done when the user click on a button and the script will then select a random div from a list of them (they are classes as "assignment")
I want to do the same thing, but instead when this particular page(which is a DIV) is loaded.

Comment: A page is not a DIV.  That makes no sense.  Pages contain divs.

Comment: forgive me for using the wrong terminology.  What I am using this for is app created in Dreamweaver using phonegap.
So how can I trigger this script when this div is revealed/made active/whatever?   @Derek is the "div" part in that the name of the div?

Comment: @user1114118 - `$("div")` means `every <div>`.